# PHP - How to GET and process a lot of variables without slowing things down

Tags: php, performance, get

My website has a "simple" search form with 4 optional parameters sent with GET.
Each variable in the URL is processed to dynamically build a prepared statement SELECT query.

So for each optional variable, I do this :

```
if(!empty($_GET['gm'])) {
$value[]=$_GET['gm'];
$queryPart[] = 'gm=?';
$type[]='i'; // Check if Integer, string etc
}
```

I have no problem with that but now I'm working with an "advanced" search form that has 30+ optional parameters and I don't think using 30+ "If" is gonna make it in terms of performance.

I was thinking of using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php) but then I'd still have to check the existence of each variables in the array, but is it better that simple "ifs" ?
So what is the best practice for a situation like this ?

Thank you !

Comment: 30 if statements are absolutely negligible in terms of “performance”. (Whether that’s a good way of writing understandable and maintainable code, would be another question. You could for example use an array of parameter names that you go through in a loop, and then check for each of them if it exists …)

Comment: 30 isn't that many, and I seriously doubt parsing the input will be anything like the most expensive part of the operation.  What makes you think parsing 30 parameters would be expensive?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements shouldn't slow you down as much as you think it will. In terms of coding, I would use parse_url just for cleanliness sake.

If all of the different options can be individually used, all the 'if's are probably your best bet.  But if some of the options are dependent on each other you could group them into a single flag in the GET that you can check.